# $x^3[f(x+1)-f(x-1)]=1$

Tags: functional-equations

Given that $x^3[f(x+1)-f(x-1)]=1$, determine $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(f(x)-f(x-1))$ explicitly.

Comment: I think you need continuity here.

Comment: If $g(x)=f(x)-f(x-1)$, then $g(x+1)+g(x)=1/x^3$. It follows that *if your limit exists*, then its value is zero. But there is no reason for it to exists: you can construct pretty wild solutions by starting from an arbitrary function on an interval of length $2$ and using the equation to continue it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-f(x-1))$ exists and it's equal to $l$, then also $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x+1)-f(x))=l$. So 
$$
2l=\lim_{x\to\infty}( f(x+1)-f(x-1))=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^3}=0,
$$ 
hence $l=0$.